Junit Mockito testcases for Service Layer
I am facing issue while writing junit mockito testcases for the below service layer class. Can someone help me writing the test cases for me.
public class BigQueryServiceImpl implements BigQueryService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlobStorageService.class);

    @Autowired
    private GeoDataRepository geoDataRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ErrorLogRepository errorLogRepository;

    @Value("${initial.full.load.limit}")
    private Long loadLimit;

    @Value("${incremental.full.load.limit}")
    private Long incrementalLoadLimit;

    @Value("${bigquery.dataset}")
    private String dataset;

    @Value("${bigquery.dataset.table}")
    private String table;



    public MessageDTO postDatatoBigquery() {

        MessageDTO result= new MessageDTO();
        try {
            List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails> geoDataDetailsListPloygon = geoDataRepository.getGeoDataForBigQuery(loadLimit);
            List<GeoDataDTO> geoDataDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();

            geoDataDetailsList = convertInterfacetoDto(geoDataDetailsListPloygon);
            Long lastFarmerId = null;

            int i = geoDataDetailsList.size() - 1;
            GeoDataDTO details = geoDataDetailsList.get(i);

            lastFarmerId = details.getOfisFarmerId();
            logger.info("Last Farmer ID:{} ", lastFarmerId);

            Map<Long, Long> farmerIdCountMap = new HashMap<>();

            farmerIdCountMap=geoDataDetailsList.stream()
                    .filter(id -> id != null)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GeoDataDTO::getOfisFarmerId, Collectors.counting()));

            Long count= 0L;
            count = findCount(farmerIdCountMap,lastFarmerId,count);

            int totalFarmerPlotCount=geoDataRepository.getTotalCount(lastFarmerId);
            List<GeoDataDTO> filteredGeoDataList= new ArrayList<>();

            if(totalFarmerPlotCount !=count){
                Long finalLastFarmerId = lastFarmerId;
                filteredGeoDataList=geoDataDetailsList.stream()
                        .filter(detailsList -> !detailsList.getOfisFarmerId().equals(finalLastFarmerId))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }else{
                filteredGeoDataList=geoDataDetailsList;
            }

            List<Long> plotIdList = filteredGeoDataList.stream()
                    .map(dto -> dto.getPlotId())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<GeoDataDTO> finalFilteredGeoDataPolygonList= new ArrayList<>();

            Map<Long, String> plotIdGeoMap = new HashMap<>();

            List<Long> plotIdListFinal=new ArrayList<>();
            List<Integer> geoDbIdListFinal=new ArrayList<>();
            for (Long plotId : plotIdList) {
                try {
                    String plotGeo = geoDataRepository.getGeoJson(plotId);
                    updatePlotData(plotIdGeoMap,plotIdListFinal,plotId,plotGeo);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logError(plotId, details.getJobId(),details.getGeoUnitType(),e.getMessage(),errorType.POLYGANCONVERSION);
                }
            }

            filteredGeoDataList.forEach(dto -> {
                String updatedPlotGeo = plotIdGeoMap.get(dto.getPlotId());
                updateGeoDbIdList(updatedPlotGeo,dto,geoDbIdListFinal,finalFilteredGeoDataPolygonList);
            });
            result=insertBq(finalFilteredGeoDataPolygonList);

            Map<Long, GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails> plotIdGeoDataPinMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Long plotId : plotIdList) {
                try {
                    GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails plotGeo = geoDataRepository.getGeoJsonPin(plotId);
                    if(null != plotGeo) {
                        plotIdGeoDataPinMap.put(plotId, plotGeo);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logError(plotId, details.getJobId(),details.getGeoUnitType(),e.getMessage(),errorType.PINCONVERSION);

                }
            }

            List<GeoDataDTO> finalFilteredGeoDataPinList= new ArrayList<>();

            filteredGeoDataList.forEach(dto -> {
                GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails updatedPlotGeo = plotIdGeoDataPinMap.get(dto.getPlotId());
                setGeoData(dto,updatedPlotGeo,finalFilteredGeoDataPinList,plotIdList);
            });

             result=insertBq(finalFilteredGeoDataPinList);
             updateGeoPlotData(plotIdListFinal,geoDbIdListFinal,result,plotIdList);
        } catch (BigQueryException e) {
            logger.error("Exception in postDatatoBigquery method - Unable to push data to Big query {}",e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

Here in the code
List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails> geoDataDetailsListPloygon = geoDataRepository.getGeoDataForBigQuery(loadLimit);  

<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails>  GeoDataDetails is the nested sub interface of GeoDataRepository.


public interface GeoDataRepository
        extends RevisionRepository<GeoDataEntity, Long, Long>, JpaRepository<GeoDataEntity, Long> {

public interface GeoDataDetails {


        Long getOfisFarmerId();



        Integer getGeodbId();



        String getDataSource();


        String getCountryName();


        String getFarmerGroupName();


        String getGeo();


        String getGeoUnitType();


        Integer getJobId();


        Long getPlotId();


        String getRegionName();


        String getProductName();


        Integer getYear();


        Boolean getisActive();


    }



    @Query(value = "SELECT " +
            "   count(p.ofis_plot_id)" +
            "FROM " +

            "    geodata_sit.geo_data gd" +
            "    JOIN geodata_sit.farms f ON gd.farmer_id = f.farmer_id_fk" +
            "    JOIN geodata_sit.plots p ON f.ofis_farm_id = p.ofis_farm_id_fk" +
            " where " +

            "  gd.farmer_id=:farmerId " +
            " Group BY " +
            "    farmer_id order by farmer_id ASC", nativeQuery = true)

    int getTotalCount(@Param("farmerId") Long farmerId);


    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update geodata_sit.plots set job_id=:jobId,status='Initiated' where ofis_plot_id = ANY(:plotIds) ", nativeQuery = true)
    int updatePlotsJobId(@Param("jobId") Integer jobId,@Param("plotIds") Long[] plotIds);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update geodata_sit.geo_data set status='Initiated' where id in (:geoDbIds) ", nativeQuery = true)
    int updateGeodataJobId(@Param("geoDbIds") Integer[] geoDbIds);
}

I have started writing the testcase, but getting stuck on creating a list of objects of nested interface objects manually which should be returned from stubbing of
when(geoDataRepository.getGeoDataForBigQuery()).thenReturn(list);
{List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails>}

@Test
    public void testPostDatatoBigquery() throws Exception
      
    {
        //creating a list of objects of nested interface objects manually
        //  
         // List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails>
        //


        when(geoDataRepository.getGeoDataForBigQuery()).thenReturn(list);


    MessageDTO messageDTO = bigQueryServiceImpl.postDatatoBigquery();

    assertNotNull(messageDTO);
}


List.of(new InterfaceImpl(), new InterfaceImpl2(), new OtherInterfaceImpl()) or what exactly is giving you problems with creating instances of implementations of an interface?

**import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class BigQueryServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private BigQueryServiceImpl bigQueryService;

    @Mock
    private GeoDataRepository geoDataRepository;

    @Mock
    private ErrorLogRepository errorLogRepository;

    @Mock
    private Logger logger;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostDataToBigQuery() throws BigQueryException {
        // Prepare test data
        List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails> geoDataDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        GeoDataDTO mockGeoDataDto = new GeoDataDTO(); // Create a mock GeoDataDTO as needed

        // Mock behavior of geoDataRepository methods
        when(geoDataRepository.getGeoDataForBigQuery(anyLong())).thenReturn(geoDataDetailsList);
        when(geoDataRepository.getGeoJson(anyLong())).thenReturn("mocked_geo_json");
        when(geoDataRepository.getGeoJsonPin(anyLong())).thenReturn(new GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails());

        // Mock behavior of other methods or repositories as needed

        // Invoke the method
        MessageDTO result = bigQueryService.postDatatoBigquery();

        // Verify the result or behavior
        // Example: verify logging calls (optional)
        verify(logger).info(anyString(), any());

        // Example: verify repository interactions (optional)
        verify(geoDataRepository, atLeastOnce()).getGeoDataForBigQuery(anyLong());
        verify(geoDataRepository, atLeastOnce()).getGeoJson(anyLong());

        // Example: assert on the result, if applicable
        // assertEquals(expectedResult, result);

        // Additional verifications or assertions based on your requirements
    }

    // Add more test cases as needed to cover different scenarios and edge cases
    enter code here

}





@Test
public void testPostIncrementalDataToBigQuery() throws BigQueryException {
    // Mocked data for testing
    List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails> geoDataDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    GeoDataDTO mockGeoDataDto = new GeoDataDTO(); // Create a mock GeoDataDTO as needed
    // Mock behavior of geoDataRepository methods
    when(geoDataRepository.getGeoDataIncrementalForBigQuery(anyLong())).thenReturn(geoDataDetailsList);
    when(geoDataRepository.getGeoJson(anyLong())).thenReturn("mocked_geo_json");
    when(geoDataRepository.getGeoJsonPin(anyLong())).thenReturn(new GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails());
    // Mock behavior of other methods or repositories as needed
    // Invoke the method
    MessageDTO result = bigQueryService.postIncrementalDatatoBigquery();
    // Verify the result or behavior
    // Example: verify logging calls (optional)
    verify(logger).info(anyString(), any());
    // Example: verify repository interactions (optional)
    verify(geoDataRepository, atLeastOnce()).getGeoDataIncrementalForBigQuery(anyLong());
    verify(geoDataRepository, atLeastOnce()).getGeoJson(anyLong());
    // Example: assert on the result, if applicable
    // assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    // Additional verifications or assertions based on your requirements
}
// Add more test cases as needed to cover different scenarios and edge cases

}
}

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
